# Find row-wise minimum and return value and its corresponding column name

Tags: r

Consider the following matrix `m`:

```
    ca bsa rd zaa
ada  3   4  3   2
aca  1   4  5   2
ara  3   4  3   2
ava  3   4  5   2
```

I'm trying to find, for each row, the minimum value and return a data.frame in the form of:

```
    q   s d
1 ada zaa 2
2 aca  ca 1
3 ara zaa 2
4 ava zaa 2
```

Right now I'm doing:

```
res <- t(sapply(seq(nrow(m)), function(i) {
  j <- which.min(m[i,])
  c(q = rownames(m)[i],
    s = colnames(m)[j],
    d = m[i,j])}))

res <- data.frame(res)
res$d <- as.numeric(res$d)
```

I'm looking for a better way to build this.

It feels rather inefficient to build `res` using `c()` (coercing all the components to the same type) then convert it to a data.frame and finally change `d` to numeric in order to obtain the following structure:

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ q: Factor w/ 4 levels "aca","ada","ara",..: 2 1 3 4
 $ s: Factor w/ 2 levels "ca","zaa": 2 1 2 2
 $ d: num  2 1 2 2
```

I would also need to handle a case where there could be multiple minima

---

**Data**

```
m <- structure(c(3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2), .Dim = c(4L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(c("ada", "aca", "ara", "ava"), c("ca", "bsa", "rd", "zaa")))
```

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(melt(m))[, .SD[which.min(value)] ,.(Var1)]`

Comment: Another option is `library(matrixStats); rowMins(m)` but it will give only the value.

Comment: @akrun It works great. Consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: It's okay.  I will leave it as there, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find the column index of the minimum value for each row by using `max.col` on the negated version of the matrix.

```
col_id <- max.col(-m)
data.frame(q = rownames(m), s = colnames(m)[col_id],
           d = m[cbind(1:length(col_id), col_id)])
#     q   s d
# 1 ada zaa 2
# 2 aca  ca 1
# 3 ara zaa 2
# 4 ava zaa 2
```

Comment: As always, be aware that `max.col` has `ties.method="random"` by default, so if you have multiple minimum values, the result will change each time. Consider maybe `ties.method="first"` which is analogous to `which.max` 's logic.

Comment: anyway it's nice that `max.col` has the option

Answer (score 3):

I might do:

```
cn<-colnames(m)
data.frame(t(apply(m,1,function(x){y<-which.min(x);
           c(cn[y],x[y])})))
     X1 X2
ada zaa  2
aca  ca  1
ara zaa  2
ava zaa  2
```

Key things to save time: only calculate `rownames` once (outside the loop) and only calculate the `min` once on each iteration.

Here's a benchmark of the options so far:

```
set.seed(10151)
NN<-1000
m<-matrix(sample(NN,NN^2,T),ncol=NN,
          dimnames=list(replicate(NN,paste0(sample(letters,3,T),collapse="")),
                        replicate(NN,paste0(sample(letters,3,T),collapse=""))))

library(microbenchmark)
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  steven  26.35880  28.46085  30.84153  29.51562  30.82366  80.18648    50
  henrik  16.83619  17.47235  19.14324  18.73855  20.01433  26.63396    50
   mikec  25.25390  27.06398  28.69647  28.25848  29.46897  37.15669    50
    rawr 110.00786 118.80357 150.76281 128.73180 176.67976 292.00051    50
 richard  23.44658  25.49981  27.86844  26.72024  27.62607  78.14996    50
   akrun  26.65337  28.12803  35.52941  29.33611  33.54546  83.34182    50
  andres  53.05468  59.54172  71.10404  61.85948  71.27818 149.76439    50
```

*Note: `henrik` had a typo which I fixed incorrectly in the previous benchmark. For `akrun` I'm using the optimized `{res<-setDT(melt(m)); res[res[, .I[which.min(value)] ,.(Var1)]$V1]}`

Kicking up the difficulty, setting `NN<-2000` (two slowest removed to save time):

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
  steven 112.80108 114.06360 115.73233 115.29611 116.97757 122.3215    50
  henrik  67.16095  70.17341  93.84658  98.30461  99.96561 162.4522    50
   mikec 107.81738 110.24776 117.01182 111.64840 114.39962 166.1335    50
 richard 101.08277 104.76309 115.75823 105.96692 107.78915 206.8925    50
   akrun 101.65822 131.51744 159.14601 165.14284 183.04740 236.5955    50
```

And in case you weren't convinced, `NN<-5000`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  henrik 413.3938 422.7162 450.3574 432.1532 465.9551 707.6048    50
   mikec 705.4221 725.0111 764.4510 742.2715 801.8704 901.3484    50
 richard 695.7005 716.7905 754.1729 732.5105 778.5526 902.7917    50
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like

```
w <- apply(m, 1, which.min)
data.frame(
    q = rownames(m),
    s = colnames(m)[w],
    d = m[cbind(seq_along(w), w)]
) 
#     q   s d
# 1 ada zaa 2
# 2 aca  ca 1
# 3 ara zaa 2
# 4 ava zaa 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another. Maybe someone smarter can come up with a one-liner, but this is the best I can do, mom

```
m <- structure(c(3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2),.Dim = c(4L, 4L),.Dimnames = list(c("ada", "aca", "ara", "ava"), c("ca", "bsa", "rd", "zaa")))

(m2 <- data.frame(as.table(m * (apply(m, 1, min) == m))))
m2[m2$Freq > 0, ]

#    Var1 Var2 Freq
# 2   aca   ca    1
# 13  ada  zaa    2
# 15  ara  zaa    2
# 16  ava  zaa    2
```